# Cassandra modelling reflecting relationship values

Tags: cassandra, model, schema

In a Relational database I have a table products (pid,...) and another with property (propid,name) and another that relates the previous ones (relationid,pid,propid,value).
This means that I can relate new properties to products.
I'm trying to get a solution in Cassandra that could reflect what I got for now.
Is adding columns to an existing table in cassandra a good practice?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What are your queries? For Cassandra it is important to understand all possible queries to create a good data model. Moreover Cassandra can be not a good choice for complicated relations and mutable data

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Cassandra world.

This is the most challenging part when evolving from relational databases to Cassandra: the change of paradigms, as in Cassandra denormalizing is actually encouraged. Also, the structure of the tables should depend on the query that you need to execute, which will give you a lot of duplicated data.

There are several resources regarding these changes in [data modeling](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling), you can also find an in-depth explanation in https://datastaxacademy.com/ , in the course "DS220: DataStax Enterprise 6 Practical Application Data Modeling with Apache Cassandra™"

Comment: I think I understood the concepts and benefits of denormalization and also why to duplicate data.
Also this "issue" apperared when trying to gather all the data needed to a specific query.
thanks for your input.
I'll get a look at it.